# Smoke-тестирование сайта

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, тестирование

Как можно автоматизировать смоук-тестирование сайта?

Можно ли это сделать без написания сценария на каком-либо языке программирования? Если да, то как?

Comment: а что вы понимаете под смоук-тестирование? какие тесты?

Comment: selenium ide plugin для firefox позволяет записывать действия пользователя. Для этого вам не нужен будет язык программирования, возможно такой плагин существует и для хрома. Но как вы его будете использовать уже дело ваше, если нужно будет прикрутить в коду, то он умеет конвертировать записанный код для разных языков

Comment: В моем случае под смоук-тестированием имею ввиду что когда выложили новый билд, нужно сделать проверку что сайт вообще открывается, что работает регистрация и авторизация, открываются нужные каталоги